# Is there a way to make a solid entity (without setting the runtime identifier to shulker)?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons

The only way that I know of to make a solid entity is to set the runtime identity to `shulker`. The problem is that it will then also teleport like a shulker, which I don't want! Is there a way I can make an entity a solid block, like a shulker, but make it not teleport?

Comment: What is the entity you are planning (what does it do)? I ask because I think there is a better way using blocks

Comment: There is no way to make blocks do some stuff, like machines. I am planning to make a machine that can crush ingots, flint, stone, sandstone, gravel, and stone.

Making one with blocks would be a one-by-one crafting table. It feels weird when you actually use it.